# multiple dialog box within same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Requirement is to show dialog box on click of a button.I have created dialog box using jQuery UI. Please find the code here http://jsfiddle.net/M4QM6/32/.
ISsue is i have single function for creating dialog box, how can i show multiple dialog box within same page with each dialog box displaying different data,
When i click on dialog2 button, i need to show  a dialog box which has textArea and a submit button.Please suggest.
Below is the sample code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: true,
            width:"750",
            height:300,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go a couple routes.  Since your need for dialog content is pretty specific (textarea control - first dialog pops second dialog - etc), I would hard-code the needed divs on the page.  So, make a "#textAreaDialog" div and put the needed controls in it ad set its style to display:none.

Next, modify your function to accept parameters (the name of the div that should be popped, the funciton to execute if "OK" is clicked - and the function to execute if "Cancel" is clicked), so you're not limited to using #dialog for all of your modals and you can finely control what happens when each button is clicked (not always just closing the dialog.  Then, set event handlers for the click events of the buttons you need, and call your dialog accordingly.

html:

```
    <input type="button" id="btnPopFirstModal" Value="Open First Modal"/>

    <div id="divFirstModal" style="display:none;">
        Here is the content for the first modal
    </div>

    <div id="divSecondModal" style="display:none;">
        Here is the content for the second modal  
    </div>
```

Javascript functions:

```
    function PopDialog(divToPop, OkFunction, CancelFunction)
    {
        $("#" + divToPop).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: true,
                width:"750",
                height:300,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function() {
                        OkFunction();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function(){
                        CancelFunction();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    }

    function PopSecondModal(){
        PopDialog("divSecondModal", function(){ put code for OK Click here}, function(){put code for Cancel Click here});
    }
```

Javascript event handlers:

```
    $("#btnPopFirstModal").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        PopDialog("divFirstModal", PopSecondModal, function(){}); //empty function for cancel, but you can add your own code as needed
        return false;
    });
```

Remember, you can expand this as much as you want, adding more event handlers and custom divs to use for more tailored modals.  Also, as you can see, you can write your OK and Cancel funcitons inline when calling the PopDialog function - or you can pass it a function name (this is preferable if you're going to reuse that function).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did:

```
$(
    //when JQuery is ready
    funciton()
    {
        $('#SomeButton').on
        (
            'click', 
            function()
            {
                //Note that content could be anything (HTML, text...)
                //This dynamicly create a div to be your dialog
                $('<div>').append(content).dialog
                (
                    {
                        //autoOpen: false, I removed it you can put it back in if you need it but I dont think its important for now
                        resizable: true,
                        //I remove the double quotes here because height didn't have any but maybe it was the other way around
                        width:750,
                        height:300,
                        //I put this on false because if two or more dialog would need to be displayed at the same time you can't have them modals.
                        modal: false,
                        buttons: 
                        {
                            Close: function() 
                            {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        },
                        //this is important it destroys and remove the dynamically create dialog when you close them so you don't get 20 dialog not displayed in your html markup.
                        close:
                        function()
                        {
                            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                        }
                     }
                );
            }
        );
    }
);
```